# Why I cannot deploy my UWP service to my PC?

Tags: uwp

I learn UWP programming on my Windows 10 PC. And I learn this example step by step.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service

But finally I find that I cannot deploy the "MyAppService" project like this. Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appservice by itself is not a deployable project, it's just a WinRT component. It needs to be referenced by an application and will then be deployed automatically along with that application.